# Docker Container - Update entry point file

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I've Docker Container on Ubuntu and trying to start it that was initially setup by a professional developer (I'm a newbie with docker/container thing)

While starting the container using `docker start 16e5e9280bfe -a` I get this error

```
bash: startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

here is the list of containers

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
16e5e9280bfe        9fc1df773d19        "bash startup.sh"   9 months ago        Exited (127) 53 seconds ago                       mystifying_kapitsa
```

The Command `bash startup.sh` has a problem that the docker is not able to find the startup.sh file (probably it gets deleted) and **I dont know where this file should be created (need your help in this regards)**

I tried to edit the config.v2.json file (removing the CMD and ARG parameter) under `/var/lib/docker/containers/16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39/` but when I start the container, it get's overwritten by the system and startup.sh appears again in the file

Incase you need to know I've many overlays

```
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 09:02 09a7c19f2a8e478b75d8362915c9f324fca4a0a02e24637a1e636017ac94306d/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 09:02 1c8a6778fe9c2285a0fb9497cf033f70c04a16d66e644f93e4d332b7f68e1b5a/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jul 14  2019 1d0c600d79c41bf9b5554fa928a297ac3a359fbff1c8ef903c40809b913ea640/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jul 14  2019 407310e8d2aefdb76bd01fa1675eef1b7512885532703c9f658c14fb9bd16b5d/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 09:02 63a54717c69963a50921d0c63931674c8547ad032a13de29f585df956e3e8fa5/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 65a84394f71682bcf7eb92bb77e78525dc594b8688726e2fc2e125fe7c762f4d/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 09:02 68b4eb941a39414a13e1d20d623f1fa65951cf688e3ef221e3ce7ebb4a3bb5a1/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Oct 19  2019 758f8ce11982261aae7c2200e421952f155742cbee4421d73c2ee822b6a44d6d/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar  4  2018 7cfe53f80077d076c046ffe12bb189c0ae8397c02879e4ab82dfb2970708ff7b/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 7ea1bc5aab7bdbe917daa8ab70f02a1bbdd5fef3ccd7b5865d5f0b65cf188168/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 8726b7fc216e2caf30bc6bdfd67aac681c076fe016a3078093a327de0eb86f71/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Oct 19  2019 a051306523973e4bb6942c9d9bb58d39fe55e5a4d8ba69bd907285d321f8c361/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Mar 15 12:06 a1af7c75c5d4bdd231d5494618851ba1226adf91879e7091cf03313d8b97b89a/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Mar 15 07:26 a1af7c75c5d4bdd231d5494618851ba1226adf91879e7091cf03313d8b97b89a-init/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 09:02 aeea6b5c888be7896a298965b7163ea14343e3bf4bb5ccb8cd2a839cba66e62d/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Oct 19  2019 b44ca2240ee9a220eca0598a2f747ad1dfeb439019363189cbec85fb69a74775/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 bb8c3313a4e30681ac71c8e0279ed72ea94d4fbcb1f6cf6144ac98a238e3df34/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Mar 15 09:02 cdbbda1e3e039677378745b5e0a971fabc78d7ca37c6b3c15da45a54037da57b/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 d1edbc1173ed75f9fc4b800893975bdf3c6f2440f8483fb9e5acb817f19a7e45/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 e8b6a178f59cfa58f9821b555fbe28ae25ee64a22525271c5d8507dbaa41d553/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 eb14f3c333daad51203a19145d00d484862c2443f02ad711a28b9bad3bbdf08e/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jul 14  2019 f598570a29c2ba8a452969191bb362431d62ef33a81da9bd4ac2aabaac2027da/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Feb 27  2018 ffe7c7b1cc80b55698a1e7bc355fe48595dc07502a59f261821de01fcbc59f49/
```

This is the `config.v2.json` File - you may want to check please

```
{"StreamConfig":{},"State":{"Running":false,"Paused":false,"Restarting":false,"OOMKilled":false,"RemovalInProgress":false,"Dead":false,"Pid":0,"ExitCode":127,"Error":"","StartedAt":"2021-03-15T10:49:57.080556832Z","FinishedAt":"2021-03-15T10:49:57.114871213Z","Health":null},"ID":"16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39","Created":"2020-05-31T17:01:37.405644454Z","Managed":false,"Path":"bash","Args":["startup.sh"],"Config":{"Hostname":"16e5e9280bfe","Domainname":"","User":"","AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":false,"AttachStderr":false,"ExposedPorts":{"21/tcp":{},"22/tcp":{},"443/tcp":{},"80/tcp":{}},"Tty":true,"OpenStdin":true,"StdinOnce":false,"Env":["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","FFMPEG_VERSION=3.3.6","FDKAAC_VERSION=0.1.5","LAME_VERSION=3.99.5","LIBASS_VERSION=0.13.7","OGG_VERSION=1.3.2","OPENCOREAMR_VERSION=0.1.4","OPUS_VERSION=1.2","OPENJPEG_VERSION=2.1.2","THEORA_VERSION=1.1.1","VORBIS_VERSION=1.3.5","VPX_VERSION=1.7.0","X264_VERSION=20170226-2245-stable","X265_VERSION=2.3","XVID_VERSION=1.3.4","FREETYPE_VERSION=2.5.5","FRIBIDI_VERSION=0.19.7","FONTCONFIG_VERSION=2.12.4","LIBVIDSTAB_VERSION=1.1.0","KVAZAAR_VERSION=1.2.0","SRC=/usr/local","LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib"],"Cmd":["startup.sh"],"Image":"9fc1df773d19","Volumes":{"/var/log/":{}},"WorkingDir":"/var/www/html","Entrypoint":["bash"],"OnBuild":null,"Labels":{}},"Image":"sha256:9fc1df773d198694f22f33c823ea8a05db78dcc7ea787ffafdc6ee95008bcbab","NetworkSettings":{"Bridge":"","SandboxID":"e32693eb6d1f685f8a77187c9f9713558d49248bc47ab6b8a97045ad37856a3e","HairpinMode":false,"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"","LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"Networks":{"bridge":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"1dfe0ae53916827fbc1a6fe18387a7653f48cdc445b823cc3d42cce04a8ac242","EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"","DriverOpts":null,"IPAMOperational":false}},"Service":null,"Ports":null,"SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/e32693eb6d1f","SecondaryIPAddresses":null,"SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,"IsAnonymousEndpoint":true,"HasSwarmEndpoint":false},"LogPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39/16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39-json.log","Name":"/mystifying_kapitsa","Driver":"overlay","OS":"linux","MountLabel":"","ProcessLabel":"","RestartCount":0,"HasBeenStartedBefore":true,"HasBeenManuallyStopped":false,"MountPoints":{"/var/log":{"Source":"","Destination":"/var/log","RW":true,"Name":"5154e45a0f7d2fe5ce97d406f496474f9247e9413e4fc3ce076b59a45014c60c","Driver":"local","Type":"volume","Spec":{},"SkipMountpointCreation":false},"/var/www/demo":{"Source":"/var/www/demo","Destination":"/var/www/demo","RW":true,"Name":"","Driver":"","Type":"bind","Propagation":"rprivate","Spec":{"Type":"bind","Source":"/var/www/demo","Target":"/var/www/demo"},"SkipMountpointCreation":false},"/var/www/html":{"Source":"/var/www/html","Destination":"/var/www/html","RW":true,"Name":"","Driver":"","Type":"bind","Propagation":"rprivate","Spec":{"Type":"bind","Source":"/var/www/html","Target":"/var/www/html/"},"SkipMountpointCreation":false}},"SecretReferences":null,"ConfigReferences":null,"AppArmorProfile":"docker-default","HostnamePath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39/hostname","HostsPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39/hosts","ShmPath":"","ResolvConfPath":"/var/lib/docker/containers/16e5e9280bfea319c5094cddb4b2da71b6e461be824b119c32817e281d282f39/resolv.conf","SeccompProfile":"","NoNewPrivileges":false}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Thank you!

Comment: Normally there is a `docker build` that refers to a `Dockerfile` and in this file is a definition of where you get things like this `startup.sh` file

Comment: Thanks for the response. where should I place startup.sh file to make it work?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to reverse engineer someone else's docker build over this forum. It's probably more important to work out how and why this file was removed in the first place

Comment: Has this container ever worked? If it did there must have been some change. If it never worked, that's a different story

Comment: You shouldn't need any of the details you describe in the question – you can't directly access the content in `/var/lib/docker`, and IME it's pretty unusual to `docker start` a container.  Instead, can you provide the image's Dockerfile, and the `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file you'd normally use to start it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to find where is the startup script in the overlays of the image, container and volumes that are attached. You will need to find the last version (last layer) where the file was changed last and modify it there.

However, this is not to be done by someone who do not have in-depth understanding of the docker-engine.

But you don't need to do all this things just to enter in a stopped+failed container.
If a you need the access to the container, what you can do is to create image from the container

```
docker commit mystifying_kapitsa my_container:latest
```

Once you have the image, you can use it as a base for new images or, you  can create new container from the image like this:

```
docker exec -ti --name i_am_in my_container:latest /bin/bash
```

This will give you a shell inside the image from the container and all data that ware in the `mystifying_kapitsa` will be in.